# How to make dropdown chekbox filter widget that targets categories

Tags: html, css, wordpress, checkbox, widget

Please guys i need your help. 
I need to make a widget in wordpress with html that targets categories with checkbox and dropdown menu and it has to be able to have multiple choices.
Thanks